# regex doesn't match each part of the string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I wrote the following code to match a pattern but I can't get it.import re

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+) (\w+)")
match = pattern.findall("Hello Chelsea Hello ManU")
print(match)
```

Out:[('Hello', 'Chelsea'), ('Hello', 'ManU')]
What I try to achieve is.

[('Hello', 'Chelsea') , ('Chelsea', 'Hello') , ('Hello', 'ManU') ]

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+) (\w+)")
match = pattern.findall("Hello Chelsea Hello")
print(match)
```

Out:[('Hello', 'Chelsea')]

What I try to achieve is.

[('Hello', 'Chelsea') , ('Chelsea', 'Hello') ]

Why regex ignore the two words if match found for a later search?
How to achieve that output.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the newer [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module:

```
import regex as re

s = "Hello Chelsea Hello ManU"

matches = re.findall(r'\b(\w+) (\w+)\b', s, overlapped = True)
print(matches)
# [('Hello', 'Chelsea'), ('Chelsea', 'Hello'), ('Hello', 'ManU')]
```

Comment: exception:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'regex'

Comment: Ahh, I installed it and it worked so great :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want pairs of words, why use regex?

```
s = "Hello Chelsea Hello ManU".split()
out = [(s[i], s[i+1]) for i in range(len(s)-1)]
```

Comment: No, I wanted to know the concept it self and I represented it with this string.